# How to convert html into one line string?

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have some large templates as html:

```
<% /*   
  This is basically all the markup and interface
/* %>
<div id="test" class="test-right"></div>
  <div id="test" class="test-right"></div>
```

Which I need to have as one line string, for example:

```
<% /*\n  This is basically all the markup and interface\n*/ %>\n<div id=\"test\" class=\"test-right\"></div>\n   <div id=\"test\" class=\"test-right\"></div>
```

How can you do that?

```
original_string='test this id="one" test this id="two"'
string_to_replace_Suzi_with=\"
result_string="${original_string/"/$string_to_replace_Suzi_with}"
```

Comment: if that html is intended to further rendering linebreaks should be replaced with `</br>` not `\n`

Comment: No the framework that needs that html code he wants it as `\n' not </br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a pure `bash` way to do this, you can run them in command-line one at a time or in a script.

```
# Store the contents of the file into a variable
fileContents="$(<file)"

# Create a temporary string using 'GNU mktemp'
tempfile="$(mktemp)"

# Parameter substitution syntax to replace the new-line character by
# empty string and store it in the file identified by the temporary
# name
printf "%s\n" "${fileContents//$'\n'//}" > "$tempfile"

# Revert the temp file to original file
mv "$tempfile" file
```

But considering `bash` is slower for this trivial task, use `Awk`  by restting the `ORS` from `new-line` to `empty` string,

```
awk -v ORS="" 1 file
<% /*     This is basically all the markup and interface/* %><div id="test" class="test-right"></div>  <div id="test" class="test-right"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace newlines (carriage return) by a litteral `\n`, you can use `awk`:

```
awk -v ORS='\\n' 1 file
```

This will replace the output record separator `ORS` to a litteral `\n`.
The `1` triggers the default action in `awk`, print the entire record.